# How to calculate distance between n coordinates in python

Tags: python, coordinates, distance

I am working on a `python` project where from a function I am getting coordinate values `x, y` in a `dict` like below:

`centroid_dict = {0: (333, 125), 1: (288, 52), 2: (351, 41)}`

where `0, 1, 2` are the `objectId` and `(333, 125), (288, 52), (351, 41)` are their `(x, y)` coordinate values respectively.  I need to calculate the distance between each coordinate which means:

```
0 - 1 -> ((333, 125) - (288, 52))

0 - 2 -> ((333, 125) - (351, 41))

1 - 0 -> ((288, 52) - (333, 125))

1 - 2 -> ((288, 52) - (351, 41))

2 - 0 -> ((351, 41) - (333, 125))

2 - 1 -> ((351, 41) - (288, 52))
```

To calculate the distance, I can use:

```
def calculateDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    dist = math.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)
    return dist
```

but I am not able to think of any logic which can calculate distance between each points as the length of dict might increase in future. As of now, it is `3` but it can be `10`. Can anyone please help me give some ideas on it. Thanks

Comment: You might want to look into [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to generate a combination of all possible coordinates in your mapping; you may wish to [refer to this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements).

Comment: [kd tree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) this will help you , it is a graph prblem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use combinations from itertools to form a new dictionary with every pair of objects as key:

```
from itertools import combinations:
distances = dict()
for (id1,p1),(id2,p2) in combinations(centroid_dict.items(),2):
    dx,dy = p1[0]-p2[0], p1[1]-p2[1]
    distances[id1,id2] = distances[id2,id1] = math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)
```

The drawback of this approach is that it will systematically calculate all distances and your program may not need to access all of those values.   A more efficient approach could be to use a dictionary as a cache of distance and obtain them "on demand" using a function:

```
distanceCache = dict()
def getDist(id1,id2):
    if id1 > id2: return getDist(id2,id1) # only store each pair once
    if (id1,id1) in distanceCache: return distanceCache[id1,id2]
    x1,y1 = centroid_dict[id1]
    x2,y2 = centroid_dict[id2]
    dx,dy = x1-x2,y1-y2 
    return distanceCache.setDefault((id1,id2),math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy))
```

*This will allow you to simply clear the cache when object locations are changed without incurring an immediate delay of O(n^2) time*

*Note that you could also use the points (positions) themselves as key to the cache and also use an LRU cache (from functools)*

```
from functools import lru_cache
import math

@lru_cache(1024)
def getDist(p1,p2):
    dx,dy = p1[0]-p2[0],p1[1]-p2[1]
    return math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)

def getObjectDist(id1,id2):
    return getDist(centroid_dict[id1],centroid_dict[id2])
```

Comment: In your first example, I am not able to understand this line `distances[id1,id2] = distances[id2,id1] = math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)` can you explain what is happening here.

Comment: Assigning the distance dictionary for the pair of object id (tuples) in both orders.  (i.e. (id1,id2) and (id2 ,id1))  because it is the same distance no matter which one is the origin and which one is the destination.  This will allow calculating the distance only once per pair while providing access to the distance without having to use a specific order of object Ids.

Answer (score 1):

using solution from [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html), it is [k d tree graph problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)

Find the Euclidean distances between four 2-D coordinates:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
coords = [(35.0456, -85.2672),
          (35.1174, -89.9711),
          (35.9728, -83.9422),
          (36.1667, -86.7833)]
distance.cdist(coords, coords, 'euclidean')

array([[ 0.    ,  4.7044,  1.6172,  1.8856],
   [ 4.7044,  0.    ,  6.0893,  3.3561],
   [ 1.6172,  6.0893,  0.    ,  2.8477],
   [ 1.8856,  3.3561,  2.8477,  0.    ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. No import required.

```
def dist(key1,key2):
    return calculateDistance(*centroid_dict[key1],*centroid_dict[key2])

all_dist = []
for key1 in centroid_dict:
    all_dist.extend([dist(key1,key2) for key2 in centroid_dict if not key1==key2])
```